# BHO: getting a notification when onload finishes executing

Tags: atl, bho

I'm writing a BHO that should make a slight modification to a specific page. I'd be using `DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE`, but the problem is that the page loads more contents using AJAX on it's `onload` function.

I think the perfect solution for me would be to run my code after `onload` has returned. Is there any way to get notified when this happens?

**Edit:** Actually, its not `onload`, it's jQuery's `ready`. I'm afraid there's no clean way to achieve what I want. I guess I'll have to implement a timer and check the page periodically, although I hoped to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `DISPID_HTMLDOCUMENTEVENTS2_ONREADYSTATECHANGE` (you must advise for `DIID_HTMLDocumentEvents2`) and then use `get_readyState` from `IHTMLDocument2`.

You are lucky that your page is a specific one, you may see a specific sequence of events you can rely on. The general case indeed involves periodic poll (imho)

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that and it didn't work. The page was marked as ready too early. Well, pulling is the way to go I guess.

Comment: Ok, last advice: If you can, log each DISPID (if you have implemented Invoke yourself), and Advise for DIID_HTMLWindowEvents2. You may find a "late" event.